# Where to Add custom commands for Doctrine ORM commandline Interface?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Can anyone give a detailed explanation on how and where to add custom commands for doctrine?

Comment: Are you using doctrine within some framework?

Comment: @mickadoo 

No..i'm using it for my own appilcation.

Comment: how are you calling commands then, have you created your own script like `bin/console` in Symfony? If you're using the `vendor/doctrine/dbal/bin/doctrine-dbal.php` script itself, then I'd suggest copying it and modifying it to call `ConsoleRunner:run` with your own commands. Symfony or silex offer an easier way to add custom commands, but if you're doing everything from scratch it's possible, but might take some more effort and innovation